# ActiveMQ/Stomp debug when a message disables a consumer

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I am scratching my head trying to debug a PHP transaction that seems to error out one of my consumers. I can detect if my consumer is running by GREPping the process list, before I insert a new message, but no way of knowing what was in there before and what caused the fatal error.

My PHP consumer is roughly:

```
while($isRunning == true) { 
  try{
    if($frame = $this->stomp->readFrame()) { 
      $body = $frame->body;
      $this->stomp->ack($frame);
    }
  } catch(StompException $e) {
    $msg = 'Stomp Monitor readFrame() Callback Fail: '.$e->getMessage();
    error_log($msg);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to catch fatal errors or anything that will break it out of the infinite loop?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a top level [exception handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Perhaps there is an exception that your not catching.  Catch it and log it so you know why the process dies.

Comment: I'm currently doing a set_error_handler. So you're saying that exception handler will do a better job of catching most errors that a standard try/catch isn't going to capture (fatal errors)?